# Java/Oracle massive error on Android Studio

Tags: android, macos, kotlin

How can i repair that massive error on Android Studio?
I change java version on 'Gradle' option and nothing works.

I used that repo: https://github.com/SebastianAigner/my-bird-app 
from that course: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5_W5YKPShZ4&t=166s

After open that repo theres only that errors.
[image]

MacOS Monterey on VirtualBox
Android Studio Giraffe | 2022.3.1
Patch 1 Build #AI-223.8836.35.2231.10671973, built on August 17, 2023
Runtime version: 17.0.6+0-17.0.6b829.9-10027231 x86_64
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o.
macOS 12.0.1 GC: G1 Young Generation, G1 Old Generation
Memory: 1280M
Cores: 4
Metal Rendering is ON
Registry: external.system.auto.import.disabled=true
ide.text.editor.with.preview.show.floating.toolbar=false\

Answer (score 1):

Update your java & kotlin-JVM version in your gradle(app) as follow:

```
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_17
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_17
}
kotlinOptions {
    jvmTarget = "17"
}
```